# How to add a float with int f#

Tags: f#, addition

Simple question, i have an integer and a float. How do i find the sum of these.

I get an error saying

> "the type float did not match the type int"

```
let add x y = x + (float y)

let m = sum 2.3 2
do printfn "%A" l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `add` you have defined. I suppose that's what you meant to call, instead of `sum` in your second line.